# JQuery form.submit() not calling controller method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I have two click methods in my javascript as follows. Method 1 is hitting the controller method but after that when clicking on a button for Method 2, it is not hitting the controller. Here I dont want to use $.ajax call for submit.  I tried different ways but am not sure why method 2 is not hitting the controller. Appreciate any inputs. Thanks.

```
Method 1:

$("#selectAll").click(function () {
    var familyDetailsForm = $("#family_details");
    var enrollmentSetupId = $("#enrollmentSetupId").val();
    var eId = $("#eId").val();
    var url = "";
    if($("#isDental").val() == "true"){
        url = GlobalVars["app_url"] + "/shop/search/addAllDentalPlans?enrollmentSetupId=" +   
enrollmentSetupId+"&eId="+eId;
    }
    else {
        url = GlobalVars["app_url"] + "/shop/search/addAllHealthPlans?enrollmentSetupId=" + 
enrollmentSetupId+"&eId="+eId;
    }
    familyDetailsForm.attr("action", url);
    familyDetailsForm.submit();             

    }); 

 Method 2:

 $("#removeAll").click(function () {
 var remove_familyDetailsForm = $("#family_details");
 var remove_enrollmentSetupId = $("#enrollmentSetupId").val();  
 var planType = $("#planKind").val();
 var url = "";
    if($("#isDental").val() == "true"){
        url = GlobalVars["app_url"] + "/shop/search/removeAllDentalPlans?  
 remove_enrollmentSetupId=" +remove_enrollmentSetupId+"&planType="+planType;
    }
    else {
        url = GlobalVars["app_url"] + "/shop/search/removeAllHealthPlans?
 remove_enrollmentSetupId=" +remove_enrollmentSetupId+"&planType="+planType;
    }
    remove_familyDetailsForm.attr("action", url);
    remove_familyDetailsForm.submit();  


 }); 


  Controller:

  @RequestMapping(value = "removeAllHealthPlans", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String removeAllHealthPlans(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) 
throws Exception {
```

Comment: can you check your POST HTTP call to see which URL and status code you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

First check if your method is properly mapped. It should be rather

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/removeAllHealthPlans", ...)
```

This is of course assuming that your controller is mapped as /shop/search